# Jssor for jssor slider user is it possible to make a jssor slider with dynamic images

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I have made a jssor slider in my project it is working perfectly. I have decide to add database to my project and i want to save image address to database so i can i just add images to slider.

1.My question is it possible to dynamic images to jssor slider?

2.What i want is from database i will get all images and i will do a foreach to show images

this is how i do the code

```
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 720px; height: 480px;
            overflow: hidden;">
            <?php
                foreach (LoadImageGallery() as $value){
                    echo $value['searchresultbigimg'];
                    echo "<li><img src=\"admin/".$value['searchresultbigimg']."\"></li>";
                    echo $value['searchresultthumbnailimg'];
                    echo "<li><img src=\"admin/".$value['searchresultthumbnailimg']."\"></li>";
                }
            ?>

        </div>
```

`UPDATE`

i get this error when i tried your solution sir jssor this is what i tried
`Slides html code definition error, there must be at least 1 slide to initialize a slider.`

```
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">

            <?php
                foreach (LoadImageGallery() as $value){
                    echo $value['searchresultbigimg'];
                    echo "<div><img src=\"admin/".$value['searchresultbigimg']."\"></div>";
                    echo $value['searchresultthumbnailimg'];
                    echo "<div><img src=\"admin/".$value['searchresultthumbnailimg']."\"></div>";
                }
            ?>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can and you are on your way.

But you should use 'DIV' instead of 'LI'.

Jssor Slider slide html code is as below,

```
<div><img u="image" src="image.jpg" /></div>
```

Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/define-slides-html-code.html

Comment: i will try it and i will be back on you on this...i was able to make this work on normal slider but when i do it with jssor i had problem so i want to make it work with jssor because it look really good with jssor

Comment: Please open your page with browser, right click on the page, and then click 'view page source' to check source code, you will see there is no slide. That's to say, you got nothing from your database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this. I found the basic code for the array here http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/directory-list-spl/

```
 <?php
          // filetypes to display  
          $imagetypes = array("image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png"); 
          function getImageList($dir) 
          { 
            global $imagetypes;
            // array to hold return value 
            $imagefiles = array(); 
            // add trailing slash if missing 
            if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir = "images"; 
            // open directory for reading 
            $d = new DirectoryIterator($dir) or die("getImageList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading"); 
            foreach($d as $fileinfo) { 
              // skip hidden files 
              if($fileinfo->isDot()) continue;
              $imagefiles[] = array( 
                'file' => "{$dir}{$fileinfo}" 
              ); 
            } 
            shuffle($imagefiles);   
            return $imagefiles;
          } 
        ?>
             <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 800px;">
                 <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 60px; top: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 800px; overflow: hidden;">
       <?php 
           // fetch image details 
          $images = getImageList("images/"); 
           // generate list for slideshow 
          foreach($images as $img) {
          $path = ("{$img['file']}");                   
           // display on page 
echo <<<JSDIVS

              <div>
                  <div><img data-u="image" src2="$path" style="position: relative; display: block; bottom:0;"/></div>
              </div>   

JSDIVS;
}
       ?>
                 </div>            
             </div>
```

Comment: This was the first time I wrote any PHP. This is also my first answer here. I stripped out all the code I wrote that didn't seem to answer to the question.