# Add captions and slides dynamically in jssor and show full size image in overlay by onclick

Tags: javascript, css, image, jssor

I am using the simple `jssor slideshow` with thumbnails.

In my page I am getting image captions and urls in a javascript array on page load. To use in jssor I gave the images and thumbnails an id and added src to each of them in javascript as follows:

```
document.getElementById("image1").src = "img/photography/002.jpg";
document.getElementById("thumb1").src = "img/photography/thumb-002.jpg";
```

On doing this the slides do load correctly in the correct areas but the green loading sign of slideshow remains active and the slides appear to be in the background. However when I give the urls directly in the img tags and not through javascript file it loads correctly without showing the green loading image.
Please provide a solution to this issue.

Furthermore If my slides are less than ten how to remove the extra thumbnail images borders from appearing and how to add more image and thumbnail elements dynamically in jssor using javascript if number of images exceeds that number.

Secondly how to similarly add captions in the jssor slideshow using javascript. Also I need javascript and css code for jssor to display image full size in an overlay on click.

Since I am not using the jQuery version but javascript I would like the solutions in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Re: loading issue.
Please assign image src before initialization of jssor slider. See

```
document.getElementById("image1").src = "img/photography/002.jpg";
document.getElementById("thumb1").src = "img/photography/thumb-002.jpg";
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(...;
```

Re: dynamically remove/add slide
Please add new slide element to 'slides' container or remove unused slide from 'slides' container.

Re: add captions to slide
document.getElementById("slide0").appendChild(...

Re: display image full size in overlay

```
        function DisplayFullSizeImage(slideIndex) {
            //do something to display full size image
        }

        jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_CLICK, DisplayFullSizeImage);
```

Btw, there is a better way to populate html code for your slider dynamically.

Reference:

[Jssor - how to add slides dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797672/jssor-how-to-add-slides-dynamically)

[Jssor for jssor slider user is it possible to make a jssor slider with dynamic images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718583/jssor-for-jssor-slider-user-is-it-possible-to-make-a-jssor-slider-with-dynamic-i)

Comment: I did get the initialization issue resolved but for the next three I would need more help with clear examples. 1) please provide the api calls for adding and removing slides because the javascript file is very long and I could not figure out which functions to call for adding and removing slides 2) similarly please provide an example with api calls for adding captions to slides. 3) I tried to implement the overlay by showing/hiding a div with image at full size by setting its z index value to 10000.But the image gets shown inside the slider and not in overlay which also disables the slider.

Comment: Re 1:It's not allowed to add slide after initialization of the slider. You'd populate all slides before initialization. Re 2:document.getElementById("slide-0").appendChild(yourCaptionElement); Re 3: Retrieve image src and show it in your own standalone lightbox (or something else).